# Spring Security: authorize on two or more web applications simultaneously

Tags: spring, security, authentication, spring-security, simultaneous

Can you please give me a hint, how to authorize user on few web applications at the same time?

I have:

- EAR
- - WAR 1 (example.com/)
- - WAR 2 (example.com/shop/)
- - ...
- - WAR n (example.com/forum/)

Every WAR is a Spring MVC (+Security) based application. User is authenticated and authorized on WAR 1. When he swithes to any other WAR, he have to pass authentication again. How to bypass it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use [CAS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html) feature from spring security for this.

Comment: CAS is great, by too heavy-weight solution, I beleive it is just Spring Sequrity configuration problem.
But will use CAS if won't find any simpler thing.

Comment: another simple solution(hack!!) you can do store credential information from one application into cookie and force another application to auto login with remember-me. but you should take care about direct login

Comment: Wow, it's interesting solution. Jigar, will I break the standard "remember-me" functionality this way?

Comment: Yes, because when you write explicitly cookie from app1 and navigate to app2 it works but when user closes browser and try to open app2 directly then he will be logged in directly even though he has not asked from remember-me. To resolve this problem you have to store some extra info in cookies like weather this cookie is generated by spring-security or by app. and then extend spring security remember-me authentication process and verify cookie and explicty field.

Comment: Ok. After playing with some possible solutions (including: Tomcat SSO valve, OAuth for Spring Security, CAS, "remember-me" cookie and front-end redirector), CAS won. Of all the bad decisions had to choose the least worst.